# Undefined method on create with has_many and belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship, belongs-to

When i try to access to a method created by the relationship has_many - belogs_to, i get an undefined method error . Here is the code (semplified) :

local.rb (model) :

```
class Local < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foods, dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => 'local_id'
end
```

food.rb :

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :descrizione, :nome, :prezzo, :voto
   belongs_to :local, :foreign_key => 'local_id'
end
```

the /locals/show.html.erb view that calls the create action on foodsController :

```
...

<%= form_for :food, :url => {:controller  => :foods, :action => :create} do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

foods_controller.rb

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @food = @local.foods.build(params[:food])
    end
end
```

The problem is raised here in foods_controller on create action : "undefined method 'foods' ' . Why? the relationship should enable the local.foods method?
(@local is defined in locals_controller.rb, @local = Local.find(params[:id]) , and local_id attribute is defined in schema.rb and in the last db migration , just to be clear)

Thank you

Comment: Can you give more details? Is it saying @local is nil?

Comment: @local is not nil, tell me what others details you need

Comment: Since @local is defined in a different controller, wouldn't it not be accessible from FoodController?

Comment: How are you accessing @local, which is defined in the locals controller, from the foods controller?

Comment: What's the full error message. Please post that.

Comment: @ elevine i think no as a matter of fact the problem isn't raised from locals
@ davidrac , @ local since defined in one controller isn't accessible through also the other controllers ?

Comment: the error is undefined method 'foods' for nil:NilClass raised by foods_controller in 'create'

Comment: I think that error is telling you that you are trying to call the foods method on a nil object, which is @ local in this case.  A quick way to check this is to try 'puts @local' on the previous line and see what you get in the console.

Comment: i've try to do puts @ local but the error does not change so it's @local the problem? or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `@local` is defined in a different controller, you won't be able to access it from FoodController.

Comment: can i write a method called current_local in locals_helper that let me retrive the current local?

Comment: I don't think you want a helper method.  Do you just want to save the food object into your database?  If so, you should be able to do: Food.new(params[:food]).save

Comment: yes i want to do that, but with a local associated to every food, can you help me?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that?  Why not just query the database when you need the data and pass it to your view?

Comment: the purpose it's due to this specific program, and because i'm following a tutorial and i want to understand how does it works.
The view that contains the form for a new food is the one that show a specific local, so on create i need that new food contains that specific local_id and so create "automatically" the relationship between the new food and the local (already visualized)

Comment: @giulyquinto Without more details, its difficult to really understand what you are trying to accomplish.  I think it would be more effective if you started a new question, which linked to the tutorial you are using, and described your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `accepts_nested_attributes_for` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). I think this is the standard way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: in a couple of hours i'll try

Comment: But the relationship between models creates methods itself, doesn't?

Comment: i've tried o put accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods in local.rb and change the create action of food_controller in @food = local.foods.build(params[food]) but 'local' isn't defined